# How-to hanging Indent in bulleted list in Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, indentation, list

I have a document that has a particular list in the document, right now it looks like this:

[image: Current Bulleted List]

What I want to achieve is, add a hanging indent on the `My Account` line - where `image` (the wrapped content after settings: profile), lines up with either the hyphen (-) in front of -Opens, or the word 'Opens' (preferable), like so:

[image: Desired Outcome]

It would be great to line it up like the picture, but if the laws don't allow it, then so be it.

One thing to note, is that I have a tab stop right in front of the hyphens before the descriptions. This, I believe, is causing some unpredictable behavior that I cannot seem to be rid of without putting the wrapped content on its own new line. See this example of this behavior:

Here are the `Paragraph Properties`:

[image: Paragraph Properties]

This yields this **unruly** behavior:

[image: Unruly Behavior of Indents]

I must be doing something wrong. This is a nearly-fresh install of Office, and there have been no changes to the Normal template. How do I accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use two tabs to achieve this:

1. Set the paragraph hanging value to where you want the text to be indented (note that "indent" is set to zero):

[image]

2. Set two tabs, the first one determines where the text will start after the bullet and the second one where the dash will be. both must be to the left of the indentation.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally find it a lot easier to work with tables, the text never moves and it is easier to format. If you already have the list tabbed, it should be easy to convert. Go to the *Insert* ribbon, select "Convert Text to Table" from the dropdown menu, and remove all borders from the table. On the *Layout* tab select "View Gridlines" (far right), and adjust your alignment and spacing